# ¿Es posible separar el servidor vnc de la maquina a la que quiero controlar?

Tags: linux, docker

Una estructura normal es:

> [cliente vnc] -- internet --> equipoB[servidor vnc + escritorio]

Pero deseo por funcionalidad de mi aplicación hacer:

> [cliente vnc] -- internet --> equipoB[servidor vnc] --> equipoC[escritorio]

¿Es posible realizar esta configuración?
mi objetivo es controlar varios equipos de forma remota, sin instalar el servidor vnc en cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te conectas al equipoB via vnc, nada te impide estando ya en el equipoB volver a conectarte por vnc al equipoC. 
Tu ves lo que está viéndose en el equipoB, si en el equipoB estás con un clientevnc conectado a equipoC lo verás también. 
Es lo que se suele llamar "máquina de salto", entras en ella y de ahí saltas a todas las demás.